# How can i add a Custom Property like x:Name="value"?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi guys i tired to make my custom property like that in xaml for all control

```
// ... 
<TextBlock x:Name="tblck1"/>
//...
```

i want to create my one like this:

```
//...
<TextBlock g:Language="EN"/>
//...
```

i tired a static class and MarkupExtension but its seems like not the correct way! 
please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Read tutorial about `AttachedProperties`. For example from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/692265/WPF-Custom-Attached-Property)

Comment: There already are provisions for multilingual resources. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't understand why you want a custom prefix `g:` to define `Language` property.
You have two choices to achieve what you want.

**Dependency properties** from msdn

> The purpose of dependency properties is to provide a way to compute
>   the value of a property based on the value of other inputs. These
>   other inputs might include system properties such as themes and user
>   preference, just-in-time property determination mechanisms such as
>   data binding and animations/storyboards, multiple-use templates such
>   as resources and styles, or values known through parent-child
>   relationships with other elements in the element tree

**Attached Properties** from msdn

> An attached property is a concept defined by XAML. An attached property is intended to be used as a type of global property that is settable on any object. In Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), attached properties are typically defined as a specialized form of dependency property that does not have the conventional property "wrapper".

You specified that you want something like this

```
<TextBlock g:Language="EN"/>
```

If you want it to look like this

```
<TextBlock Language="EN"/>
```

Then you don't have other way but to create a custom control that derives from `TextBlock` and create a `Dependency property`.

So it'll end up with something like this

```
 <controls:CustomTextBlock Language="EN"/>
```

The other choice you have is to create an `attach property` which will end up looking like

```
<TextBlock attachProperties:ClassToDefineAttachProperty.Language="EN"/>
```

The choice is up to you.

I'd rather go with the `attached properties` though as it is easier to extend any existing class when it comes to problems like having a `Language` property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys i finished to this code and it is work perfectly:

```
public class DesignMode : FrameworkElement
    {
        public static GAppLanguage GetDesignLanguage(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (GAppLanguage)obj.GetValue(DesignLanguageProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDesignLanguage(DependencyObject obj, GAppLanguage value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DesignLanguageProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DesignLanguageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DesignLanguage", typeof(GAppLanguage), typeof(DesignMode), new PropertyMetadata(GAppLanguage.EN, new PropertyChangedCallback(DesingLanguageChanged)));

        private static void DesingLanguageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DesignMode.DesignLanguage = (GAppLanguage) Enum.Parse(typeof(GAppLanguage),e.NewValue.ToString());
        }

        public static GAppLanguage DesignLanguage { get; set; }
    }
```

and i use it in my xaml like this:

```
<TextBlock  Text="{GtringResource gtringtest}" d:DesignMode.DesignLanguage="EN" />
```